# Nonlinear (statistical) analysis of data

Tags: nonlinear

Suppose I have a dataset with $2$ columns $X$ and $Y$. Now I want to test a specific scenario as I suppose that there might be occasions where there is a relation between the outcome Y and the position of $X$ in between a modulo $2^n$ smaller than $X$ and a modulo $2^{n+1}$ greater than $X$. My questions now are:

1. Is this a known field of investigation?
2. Any commands in R or Pari/GP that can help me?

Comment: Could you make your discussion a little less abstract? I'm not certain I have correctly understood what you're asking for.

Comment: X=(2=2^1,3,4=2^2,5,6,7,8=2^3,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16=2^4, ...);Y=(1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0, ...). These columns have basically an infinite amount of rows. I suspect, there might be a pattern appearing if we would do certain analyses: example: for X=3=2^2-1=-1 modulo 2^2 then Y=1. Also for X=7=2^3-1=-1 modulo 2^3 then Y=1. Then, I would like to examine if this keeps on holding for ever. Now, this example clearly doesn't hold but I would like to test more complicated examples that might hold or just have statistical tool to find what does hold.

Comment: You can never confirm something "holds forever" --- you can only check that it *doesn't hold* or that it has held so far. It's still not quite clear to me in several respects. (1) Is the rule to  generated by you, or automatically? (2) Is the rule you're checking one you arrive at from the data or is it from some external consideration? (3) Is this relationship meant to be purely deterministic (and if so, under which category of our [on topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) list does it fall)?

Comment: the X colum are just the natural numbers. Y is 1 if X is prime or 0 if it is not. Because the range between 2^n and 2^(n+1) becomes bigger and bigger, it would be a special case to find an exact formula like 2^(2n)-n is always prime. But maybe if we distribute everything between 2^n and 2^(n+1) on a unit circle, we could come to a statement that for angles between 35 and 45 degrees we have a high liklyhood to find primes.

Comment: I mean that I want to split "all" ranges of X from 2^n to 2^(n+1) together with the Y values on a unit circle and investigate the Y values for "all" values of X and investigate if there is a pattern.